# Finding mixed XML content with regular expressions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

During the running of my XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, I have need to find certain text (e.g., "story 3.1", "story 8.19", "story 21.76") and do something with it (e.g., wrap it in a hyperlink). Finding these instances and doing what I want with them were simple tasks. The problem I've run into though is that sometimes I might have mixed content that needs to be wrapped in the hyperlink (e.g., "story 3.1<i>a</i>"). I've not been able to figure out how to do that.

Here is some sample data and my template:

```
<p>Jack goes up the hill (story 3.1<i>a</i>) to fetch a pail of water.</p>

<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:variable name="content" as="xs:string" select="."/>
<xsl:analyze-string select="$content" regex="Story [0-9]*\.[0-9]*" flags="i">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:variable name="figureToTargetId">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]*\.[0-9]*">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('s',.)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <a href="#{$figureToTargetId}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>        
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above case I'd want "story 3.1<i>a</i>" to be wrapped in the hyperlink.

I know to ideally get around this I'd have to match on something other than text(). I'm not sure what that is though.

One approach I've been exploring is looping through the text node set using xsl:for-each and testing whether the next text node is exactly one alpha character long. If it is, then wrap it in the same hyperlink as the previous text node. (For various reasons, I know that any one alpha character long text node after a text node that matches the above reg ex should be hyperlinked to the same target.) But I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you post some more input samples and the corresponding output you need? It sounds as if `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="i[matches(., '^[a-z]$')]">...</xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>` (perhaps with `*` for `i` or some other pattern) can help but I need to see more details on the input and wanted output to spell out a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/text()[matches(., 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)')]">
    <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="pContent" select="string(.)"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$pContent" regex="Story [0-9]*\.[0-9]*" flags="i">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="figureToTargetId">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]*\.[0-9]*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('s',.)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <a href="#{$figureToTargetId}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:if test="not(matches($vCur, 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+).+$'))">
          <xsl:sequence select="$vCur/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
         </xsl:if>
        </a>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
  "p/*[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
         [self::text()
        and
          matches(., 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$')]
         ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this document** (the provided one extended to contain both interesting cases):

```
<t>
    <p>Little Red Riding Hood (Story 3.1) </p>
    <p>Jack goes up the hill (Story 3.1<i>a</i>) to fetch a pail of water.</p>
</t>
```

**Produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
      <p>Little Red Riding Hood (<a href="#s3.1">Story 3.1</a>) </p>
      <p>Jack goes up the hill (<a href="#s3.1">Story 3.1<i>a</i>
      </a>) to fetch a pail of water.</p>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

We check to see if the matched substring is a suffix of the current text node -- if yes, then we also copy the first following sibling element.

**Update**:

In a comment the OP has set a new, additional requirement -- also change `<i>` to `<em>`.

**This requires only a slight update to the above solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/text()[matches(., 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)')]">
    <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="pContent" select="string(.)"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$pContent" regex="Story [0-9]*\.[0-9]*" flags="i">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="figureToTargetId">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]*\.[0-9]*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('s',.)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <a href="#{$figureToTargetId}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:if test="not(matches($vCur, 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+).+$'))">
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="match" select="$vCur/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
         </xsl:if>
        </a>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
  "p/*[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
         [self::text()
        and
          matches(., 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$')]
         ]"/>
 <xsl:template mode="match" match=
  "p/i[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
         [self::text()
        and
          matches(., 'Story [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$')]
         ]">
  <em><xsl:apply-templates/></em>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre! That works beautifully and has the elegance I was hoping for.

Comment: Hi, Dimitre, is there a way to apply-templates to the selected sequence such that the sequence are processed according to the appropriate matching template rule? (In this particular stylesheet, the <i> should actually become <em>.)

Comment: I should clarify... I know how to apply-templates to it (change <xsl:sequence to xsl:apply-templates), but then the suppression from the second template is not working and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @SteveoDevo, You are welcome. If you find my solutions interesting, you may have a look at the ones I consider as accomplishments -- they are in my favorites.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre. I am definitely going to check them out along with the resources you list for learning XSLT 2/XPath 2. I'm trying to figure out how to take my skills to the next level.